# reading a bash command result

Tags: shell, lua, awesome-wm

I used to use the "`execute_command`" found in the former awesome wiki. This command uses `io.popen` and the `lines` method to return the command's result.
Now, the doc's advice is to avoid `io.popen`.

My rc.lua uses `io.popen` to assign hostname's computer to a variable ordinateur (I'm trying to maintain a unique rc.lua for two quite different computers).

I used to have this line :
    ordinateur=execute_command( "hostname" )
I replace it with :

```
awful.spawn.easy_async_with_shell( "hostname" ,    
   function(stdout,stderr,reason,exit_code)
       ordinateur = stdout                                                      
   end)
```

Further in the script, I have tests like 
    if ordinateur == "asus" then ....
But it fails. Actually ordinateur is nil
I think the rc.lua is read before ordinateur gets its assignment, right ?

So, what can I do ? I'm thinking replace the command with the reading of the `/etc/hostname` file, is that better ?  How am I going to do this with awful.spawn.* commands ?

Thank you
David

Comment: This should be a valid use of io.popen. You may ignore the docs here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at all possible, use LuaSocket.

```
> socket = require "socket"
> print(socket.dns.gethostname())
myhost
```

Another option is to run `hostname` from the script that launches the window manager, and store the result in an environment variable.  Who knows, if you're lucky, it's already in there?!

```
> print(os.getenv("HOSTNAME") or os.getenv("HOST"))
myhost
```

Comment: Or `print(os.getenv("HOSTNAME") or os.getenv("HOST"))`

Comment: Actually I get `nil` using `os.getenv` and I don't want to create an environment variable. So I choose your LuaSocket solution. I had put your code to the top of my rc.lua and it's doing the job! Thanks!

Comment: lhf, that's great - I've added that into the answer.  david, glad the LuaSockets solution worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

It fails later in the script because the command is asynchronous. This means it Awesome keeps going during the command execution and the result will be available later.

This is the whole point of not using `io.popen`. `io.popen` will *stop* everything [related to X11, including all applications] on your computer while it is being executed.

You need to modify your code so all things that access `ordinateur` do so *after* the callback has been called. The easiest way to do so is adding that code in the callback.